# How to fetch product image urls on a product page?

Tags: bigcartel

I'm building a custom theme for my bigcartel store. Trying to implement a share button, and I would like to insert the first image's URL into the share control. How do I access the first image only? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When on the Product page, or whenever you have a `product` variable available to you - you can retrieve the first image using:

`{{ product.image | product_image_url }}`

Also documented here:

https://developers.bigcartel.com/api/themes#product

```
product.image   Returns the default image of a product.
product.images  Returns all of the images of a product.
product.image_count Returns the number of images a product has
```

Comment: that one is much easier than what I came up with! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

You would want to launch a for loop with a *limit* value specified (see below)

```
{% for image in product.images limit:1 %}
  First image URL: {{ image.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Apparently you can loop through any available array this way.

Found it in [BigCartel documentation](https://developers.bigcartel.com/api/themes#for-loops)